# Finitely many $\alpha$ s.t. all conjugates $\leq N$ ($N \geq 1$)

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $K$ be a number field, and let $N \geq 1$. Then there are only finitely many $\alpha \in O_K$ such that all
> conjugates of $\alpha$ have complex absolute value $\leq N$.

The solution goes as follows:

> Let $s_1, \cdots , s_n$ be the elementary symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables. Let
> $σ_1,\cdots , σ_n$ be the complex embeddings and denote $α_i = σ_i(α)$ for $i =
> 1, \cdots , n$. If $|α_i| ≤ N$ for all $i$, then $|s_k(α_1, \cdots , α_n)| ≤ 2^nN^n$
> for any $1 ≤ k ≤ n$. In particular, there are only finitely many integral polynomials $x_n − s_1x^{n−1} + \cdots + (−1)^ns_n$ satisfying this bound. It implies that
> there are only finitely many $α$ with conjugates of bounded complex absolute
> value.

My bound would be $(nN)^n$, arguing as follows :

Arguing for $1 \leq k \leq n$, each $s_k$:

- sums at $ \leq n^n$ different terms.
- each summed term is the product of at most $n$ Terms $\leq N$ and thus each such term is $\leq N^n$.

Combining the two using absolute values everywhere gives $|s_k| \leq (nN)^n$.

How do attain the $2$?

Comment: The number of products in the sum [$s_k(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) is $\binom nk.$

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Now it feels as if we are somehow considering the powerset of ($X:= \{ \alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n\}$), and doing $2^{X}N^n$. Which I don't get.

Comment: I am not considering that powerset, but I get $\binom nk,$ which is $\le\sum_i\binom ni=2^n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! (That sum can be interpreted as being exactly the cardinality of that Powerset) :)

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes you did answer it, which is why I said Thanks. The second part of my comment was just meant to point out that this sum actually does relate to the powerset, (I hope I make sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Anne Bauval](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/386889/anne-bauval):

> The $2^n$ stems from the fact that:
> $$ \binom{n}{k} \leq \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$$

Since $s_k$ consists of $\binom{n}{k}$ different summands, each summand being the product of at most $n$-terms $\leq N$, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
    |s_k| \leq \binom{n}{k} N^n \leq \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} N^n \leq 2^nN^n 
\end{align*}